# Modal popup does not load on button click

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am trying to open a modal popup after a click of a button but I am getting the following error:

It clicks on the button but somehow does not load the popup after the button click event.

```js
test.only('Create Template', async({ page })=>{

  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000');
  await page.click('text=Templates');
  await page.click('text=Create Template');
  await page.waitForURL('http://localhost:Templates');

  });
```

```html
racing.stop
— 1ms
browserContext.newPage
— 272ms
page.goto
(localhost:3000)
— 990ms
locator.click
(text=Templates)
— 206ms
locator.click
(text=Create Template)
— 476ms
page.waitForURL()
waiting for navigation to "http://localhost:Templates" until "load"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`waitForURL` will wait for that url in the same page. It won't listen to a new page (popup). You can wait a new page from the context instead:

```
const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
  context.waitForEvent('page'),
  page.click('text=Create Template'),
]);
console.log(await newPage.evaluate('location.href'));
```